# React Image Upload to Spring Boot Server fails

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, fetch, multipartform-data, antd

Image upload api is working from postman and swagger but not from react application.

Always rejecting with 415 -

error: Unsupported Media Type and

exception - org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

message - "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzA5My2dyhAyxoPIZ' not supported",

My image upload API code looks like this in Spring Boot -

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/profilepic/{userId}", "/profilepic/{userId}/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<GenericResponseREST>> uploadEmployeePicture(
    @Valid @NotNull @PathVariable(value = "userId") Integer employeeId,
    @NotNull @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws URISyntaxException {
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<GenericResponseREST>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        userControllerAsync.uploadEmployeePicture(result, employeeId, file, clientInfoService.generateRequestorInfo(servletRequest));
        return result;
}
```

This works. We checked both from swagger and postman. Although, from postman if we provide any content-type it fails, only if we keep the content-type blank it works.

Anyway, in my react-redux application, I have used antd upload to fetch the file and used fetch-whatwg to upload the file. Here's the antd upload code -

```
export default class extends Component {

    beforeUpload(file) {
        const isJPG = file.type === 'image/jpeg';
        if (!isJPG) {
            notification('error', 'You can only upload JPG file!', '');
            return false;
        }
        const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
        if (!isLt2M) {
            notification('error', 'Image must smaller than 2MB!', '');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        const {user, uploadProfilePicture} = this.props;
        const onImageUpload = function (info) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = (obj) => {
                const imageDataAsURL = obj.srcElement.result;
                uploadProfilePicture(user.id, imageDataAsURL);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(info.file.originFileObj);
        };
        return (<Upload
                            className="avatar-uploader"
                            name="avatar"
                            showUploadList={false}
                            beforeUpload={this.beforeUpload}
                            //customRequest={this.upload}
                            onChange={onImageUpload}
                        >
                            {user.avatar ? (
                                <img src={user.avatar} alt="" className="avatar"/>
                            ) : (
                                <img alt="#" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png'/>
                            )}
                            <Icon type="plus" className="avatar-uploader-trigger"/>
                        </Upload>
      );
```

The api calling code with fetch-whatwg is like below -

```
function uploadProfilePicture(id, file) {
    const updateUserURL = API_BASE_URL + USERS.UPDATE + id;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzA5My2dyhAyxoPIZ',
            'token': authService.getTokenFromLocalStorage()
        },
        body: formData
    };
    return fetch(updateUserURL, options)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
            }
            const error = new Error(response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.user;
        });
```